# How to calculate that no sub range overlap each other and all sub range covers whole range in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, range

I have a range in java implemented as a class which is divided into sub-ranges. The implementation is roughly as follows:

```
public class Range
{
   static public class Key implements Comparable<Key>
   {
      public int start;
      public int end;
      ...
   }

   Key range;
   SortedMap<Key, Range> subRange;
}
```

I want to make a function that makes sure that no subrange overlaps each other and the combined range of the subrange covers total range completely. Start and end of each range may be equal.

Example of a valid object:

```
Range: start 1, end 10
  subrange 1: start 1, end 2
  subrange 2: start 3, end 9
  subrange 3: start 10, end 10
```

What would be the best way to implement this?

EDIT:

To anyone interested in the implementation:

In my validation code I do these steps:

1. Convert the sorted map to an Array
2. Force the first and last element to cover the beginning and end of total range
3. Iterate array elements and fix gaps or overlap between them

Code for step 3:

```
for (int i=0; i < (rangeArray.length - 1); i++)
{
    if (rangeArray[i].range.end < (rangeArray[i+1].range.start - 1) ||
        rangeArray[i].range.end >= rangeArray[i+1].range.start)
    {
        // Alternatively, lose the if and just force subrange to behave this way
        rangeArray[i].range.end = rangeArray[i+1].range.start - 1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Avee,

Can you please post your code?
I am have to perform similar validation, and I'm not able to come up with something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Amit, this is what I ended with:

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question to include a snippet of my implementation, I hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `subRange` map is sorted, you can iterate over it and check that there is no gap in the sequence of `end` to the next `start`. And of course from your total starting point to the first `start` and your last `end` to your total ending point. Apply this check recursively to all `subRange`s, too.

For this your map has to be sorted by `start`, which is the case in your example.

Comment: This solves the problem, thanks a bunch! In addition to checking for gaps, I also check for overlapping subRanges in each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to do the sum of all the ranges and compare it to the delta of the maximum and minimum values across all ranges. If the sum is greater or equal to the delta, that means there's intersection.